# The meaning of a long gaze : supposed to indicate agreeableness in new-borns but suprise in infants

Tags: cognitive-psychology, perception

Several studies on new-born and infant are based on the gaze, but depending on the age of the subject, the assumption is different. For new-born, a long gaze is supposed to mean that what they look at is [agreeable](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S016363839890011X). For infants, a long gaze is supposed to means that they are [surprised](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/348/6230/91).

On what are these two assumptions based? Can they be verified? 
If yes, at what age does the meaning of a long gaze change? And why does it change?